# Add panda column values using append() & DataFrame.columnName yet no column values are update in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Purpose**

Add values to data frame in Pandas.

It's a simple assignment for adding a column to a data frame and then updating the value of columns while inside a for...loop.

The predict.score from the model runs ok and have values for Accuracy, Precision, Recall, etc. I have printed these values, now I desire to move the values into to a data frame structure.

First step, create a new empty data frame with column names:

```
df_score = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'F1', 'Recall', 'Estimators', 'Depth', 'Max_node'])
```

**Second step**

Update values. I have tried two methods to update column values, still no success in updating column values

***Method 1***: Append() function to add column values

```
df_score.append([predict.score(X_test, y_test), precision_score(y_test, pred), e, d, node])
```

***Method 2***: Dataframe reference to column to add values

```
df_score.Accuracy = predict.score(X_test, y_test)
df_score.Precision = precision_score(y_test, pred)
df_score.Estimators = e
df_score.Depth = d
df_score.Max_node = node
```

***Method 3***: [[]] reference to data frame

```
df_score[["Accuracy"]] = predict.score(X_test, y_test)
df_score[["Precision"]] = precision_score(y_test, pred)
df_score[["Estimators"]] = e
df_score[["Depth"]] = d
df_score[["Max_node"]] = node
```

***Method 4:***: AFTER for..loop, I can append dict() a to the data frame, BUT still within the for...loop, not value assignments are working...

```
df_score.append(a,ignore_index=True)
Accuracy    Precision   F1  Recall  Estimators  Depth   Max_node
0   0.9 0.9 NaN NaN 200.0   15.0    40.0
```

**Problem**

I have followed these examples and they appear correct, but I'm still missing some facet of the data frame column update for columns, thus far, no values are update via either method.

```
>>df_score 
Accuracy    Precision   F1  Recall  Estimators  Depth   Max_node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to `dict` and use `append`

```
df_score = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'F1', 'Recall', 'Estimators', 'Depth', 'Max_node'])

data = dict(
Accuracy = 0.95,
Precision = 0.95,
F1 = 0.95,
Recall = 0.95,
Estimators = "Estimators",
Depth = "Depth",
Max_node = "node")

df_score.append(data,ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    Accuracy    Precision   F1   Recall  Estimators  Depth   Max_node
0   0.95        0.95        0.95  0.95   Estimators  Depth   node
```

Comment: When I try: data = dict(Accuracy=predict.score...), I get an invalid syntax on the '=' assignment

Comment: @user1857373 copy your code it seem you got syntax error

Comment: a = dict([Accuracy=leaf.score(X_test, y_test), Precision=precision_score(y_test, pred), Estimators=e, Depth=d, Max_node=node])
            df_score.append(a,ignore_index=True)

Comment: for e in model_estimate:
    for d in model_depth:
        for node in List_leaf_nodes:
            leaf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = e, max_depth = d, max_leaf_nodes = node).fit(X_train, y_train)
            pred = leaf.predict(X_test)
            a = dict(Accuracy=leaf.score(X_test, y_test), Precision=precision_score(y_test, pred), Estimators=e, Depth=d, Max_node=node)
            df_performance_score.append(a,ignore_index=True)

Comment: {'Accuracy': 0.9,
 'Precision': 0.9,
 'Estimators': 200,
 'Depth': 15,
 'Max_node': 40} is my last for..loop value on this dict() structure

Comment: that worked for a single try BUT when I apply this approach within my for..loop, nothing works to update

Comment: @user1857373 just add df_performance_score=df_performance_score.append(a,ignore_index=True) to the last line line your not affecting the new dataframe

Comment: thanks, that was my part a oversight on returning the df_score = df_score to receive the update to the data frame, thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a list then convert it to a df.

```
temp_list = []

temp_list_item = [predict.score(X_test, y_test), precision_score(y_test, pred), e, d, node]
temp_list.append(temp_list_item)
                        
    
new_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_list, columns = ['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Estimators', 'Depth', 'Max_node'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 3 should be used like this:

dataFrameName["columnName"] = LIST/Numpy Array

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
arr = [1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
df["A"] = arr
print(df)
```

Comment: I have the pd.DataFrame(columns=['Accuracy') defined. BUT when I try df_score["Accuracy"] = predict.score(X_test, y_test) using single [], I still do not get values, this I have inside a for...loop

Comment: @user1857373 because that assign 3 new rows to Accuracy column to your dataframe while your dataframe empty and other columns has no values so it dosnt work

Comment: I see, so when I create my data frame, I need to at least add some dummy values to establish columns...

Comment: @user1857373 can you tell me what predict.score(X_test, y_test) returns, is it an np.array, list or anything else?

Comment: @user1857373 defining empty dataframe is totally fine, that method with single [] should work.

Comment: predict.score returns a numpy.float64' object

Comment: when I try df_score["Accuracy"] = 99 assignment in the for..loop, I still have an empty data frame

Comment: @user1857373 that happened because for this type of assignment the object needs to be iterable like a list, try wrapping the number 99 around []

Comment: @user1857373 same problem occurs with your predict.score method, call the method inside a list like [predict.score()], it should work fine then